# curl error: 7 Failed to connect to www.******.com port 80: Connection timed out

Tags: php, curl

I am writing code to get content from other URL curl.
My code is working fine on localhost but when I uploaded on server its not working.

It showing **curl error:**

> curl error 7,Failed to connect to www.******.com port 80: Connection
>   timed out.

This is my **Code**

```
function get_data($url) {

    //echo $url;
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$data ) {
     echo "curl error->".curl_errno($ch)."->".curl_error($ch);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;    
}
```

Comment: Where did you host your script? Most online hostings are blocking CURL requests.

Comment: Nothing we can do here. Your network connection fails. Period. Either your firewall blocks outgoing requests (not very likely) or that remote site blocks your requests. Are you sure they allow scraping their website? You may run into legal issues otherwise...

Comment: don't use shared hosting for this. get a $25 per month linode or digital ocean vps.

Comment: You can try with file_get_contents("http://www.");